# Ensure a trailing character is included as a string in Python

Tags: python

What is the best method in Python for ensuring a trailing character is included as a string in Python?

One example: A user supplied URL in a script needs to be used to construct a URL, and so we want to ensure that a trailing slash is included in the URL, or else add one ourselves.

So, given the strings `http://www.so.com` or `http://www.so.com/`, what is the best way to ensure you end up with `http://www.so.com/`?

My solution uses the `re` module, but as I am still learning Python I was wondering if there was a better practice to solving this problem.

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://www.so.com"
>>> re.sub('//$', '/', re.sub('$',  '/', url))
'http://www.so.com/'
>>> url = "http://www.so.com/"
>>> re.sub('//$', '/', re.sub('$',  '/', url))
'http://www.so.com/'
```

**UPDATE**

I should clarify that I am looking for a purely Python solution, without having to use any extra modules. Just a part of learning Python tricks and best practices.

Comment: Instead of manipulating paths by hand, I would use `urllib.parse` for this kind of thing. Then you don't have to worry about the trailing `'/'`. You can use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to build the URL.

Comment: indeed, I can use the urljoin module, this was just an example for the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) "Best practices" questions are strongly discouraged here.

Comment: And there is nothing more "purely Python" than using the standard library!

Comment: I would consider built-in modules to be "purely Python." I can understand not wanting to use third-party packages, but the built-ins are there for a reason. [Python is "batteries included"](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/stdlib.html#batteries-included), and learning how to use the standard library is an essential part of learning Python.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts and info, will continue to investigate built-in modules as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access to end of a string with `[-1]` index :

```
>>> url = "http://www.so.com"
>>> if url[-1]!='/':
...  url+='/'
... 
>>> url
'http://www.so.com/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the purely Python answer!

Answer (score 2):

For an application like this, you should probably use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) ([`urlparse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) in Python 2) No need to manually manage the slashs.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
url_base = "http://www.so.com"
add = "foo/bar"

print(urljoin(url_base, add))
# http://www.so.com/foo/bar
```

For file paths, [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is an analogous function.

Answer (score 1):

For a difficult-to-read one-liner, you could do this:

```
url = "http://www.so.com"
url += ['/', ''][(url or '')[-1] == '/']
```

`(url or '')` - This part sets the url to a string by default if it's false, null, empty list, etc...

`[(url or '')[-1] == '/']` - This part is an index lookup that should have a value of `0` if the url does not end in a string and `1` if it does.

`['/', '']` - Based on the value of the previously mentioned index lookup, we will append either a slash or an empty string to the end of `url`

Comment: And no, I don't expect this to be the answer. I just wanted to add some fun critical thinking to a very broad question

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub('/?$', '/', url)
```

Examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('/?$', '/', 'http://www.so.com/')
'http://www.so.com/'
>>> re.sub('/?$', '/', 'http://www.so.com')
'http://www.so.com/'
```